# Correct syntax for using custom methods with caret package

Tags: r-caret

I get the following error in caret `trainControl()` using the custom methods syntax documented in the package vignette ([pdf](http://cran.open-source-solution.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretTrain.pdf)) on page 46. Does anyone know if this document out of date or incorrect? It seems at odds with the caret [documentation page](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/custom_models.html) where the "custom" parameter is not used.

```
> fitControl <- trainControl(custom=list(parameters=lpgrnn$grid, model=lpgrnn$fit, 
                                         prediction=lpgrnn$predict, probability=NULL, 
                                             sort=lpgrnn$sort, method="cv"), 
                             number=10)

Error in trainControl(custom = list(parameters = lpgrnn$grid, model = lpgrnn$fit, :
unused argument (custom = list(parameters = lpgrnn$grid, model = lpgrnn$fit, 
prediction = lpgrnn$predict, probability = NULL, sort = lpgrnn$sort, method = "cv", 
number = 10))
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error in R code.

Comment: Actually the Q is about the consistency of two caret documents. The actual error and R code are not important. I'd be happy to remove the example if that would put it back on topic.

Comment: Even that would be off-topic, I'm afraid. Whether 2 sources of documentation are inconsistent isn't a CV question. It should probably be posted to the r-help-listserv where the package maintainers will see it & be able to explain the issue or correct the discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

The cited pdf is out of date. The caret website is the canonical source of documentation.